# .slim to .html on rails helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, helper, slim-lang

Anyone already tried something like that?

```
Module FooHelper
  def navbar
    "li = link_to 'Blog', 'http://foo.com'
     li = link_to 'Contact', contact_path"
  end
end
```

And scape it on .slim file, to make it render normal html..

Comment: use `content_tag` helper